# Multi nested attributes with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Hey so I have three models:

1. DataSet
2. BrowseOption
3. BrowseOptionData

Similar to Ryan's railscasts (http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments) I want to have a double nested form except in ActiveAdmin.

Here is my Active Admin form:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Data Set Info" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :display_name
    f.input :description
    f.input :cover_photo, :label => "Cover Image (Recommend a pattern: 980x300)"
  end
  f.inputs "Browse Options" do
    f.has_many :browse_options, new_record: 'Add Option' do |t|
      t.input :option_name
      t.has_many :browse_option_data, new_record: 'Add record' do |b|
        b.input :tradesman_id, :as => :select, :collection => Tradesman.all.collect {|set| [set.name, set.id] }
        b.input :data
        b.input :featured
      end
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

I am getting a

```
uninitialized constant BrowseOption::BrowseOptionDatum
```

error

[image]

So the first 'has_many' works fine (I have tested) but the second 'has_many' for browse_option_data gives this error. Below are each of the models:

**DataSet Model:**

```
class DataSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :browse_options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :browse_options, allow_destroy: true 
end
```

**BrowseOption Model:**

```
class BrowseOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :data_set

  has_many :browse_option_data
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :browse_option_data, allow_destroy: true 
end
```

**BrowseOptionData Model:**

```
class BrowseOptionData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :browse_options
end
```

Any Ideas? I can't spot any typos. Let me know if you need anything more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was defining ":browse_option_data" wrong and I should have been calling for ":browse_option_datas" and also defined it this way in the Model for has_many.